# how to update hosts in user level to use git?

Tags: git

when I used git and github, it is often to see

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 130966 ms: Connection timed out
```

It could be resolved by update the hosts file(in linux, it is often in /etc/hosts).

However, I am working on a server that many people used together, which means I cannot use "sudo" and I cannot revise any file outside my "~/" directory.

So, is there any way that I can make a hosts file on my own directory and use it? or if there any other method to use git gracefully without hosts file?

It seems like this question is related to "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts". However, I found the solution which gets most approvement didn't work on my server.

In detail, the command I want to operate are many "git -C xxx pull origin 1.6.0-dev". I hope this information could be helpful.

Comment: Why are you using a hosts file at all for external URLs? You should be using DNS.

Comment: Ah....but the hosts file is for DNS analysis? isn't it? or if there any other methods I can use to modify the DNS process in my server?